# Evaluate $\int \frac{dr}{r^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p})^2 + \frac{\epsilon^2}{p^2} }}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do you solve this integral

$$ \phi = \int \frac{dr}{r^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p})^2   + \frac{\epsilon^2}{p^2}  }} $$
?

Note: It appears in the Kepler problem and it should come out the relation $\frac{p}{r} = 1 + \epsilon \cos(\phi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint...substitute $$\frac 1r-\frac 1p=u\cdot \frac {\epsilon}{p}$$ and then you have a standard $\arcsin$-type integral

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dr}{r^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p})^2 + \frac{\epsilon^2}{p^2} }}=-\int  \frac { d\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { \frac { \epsilon ^{ 2 } }{ p^{ 2 } } -\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right) ^{ 2 } }  } =-\frac { \epsilon  }{ p } \int { \frac { d\frac { p\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  }{ \epsilon  }  }{ \sqrt { \frac { \epsilon ^{ 2 } }{ p^{ 2 } } \left( 1-{ \frac { { p }^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  }{ { \epsilon  }^{ 2 } }  }^{ 2 } \right)  }  }  } =\\ =-\int { \frac { d\frac { p\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  }{ \epsilon  }  }{ \sqrt { \left( 1-{ \frac { { p }^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  }{ { \epsilon  }^{ 2 } }  }^{ 2 } \right)  }  }  } =\cos ^{ -1 }{ \frac { p }{ \epsilon  } \left( \frac { 1 }{ r } -\frac { 1 }{ p }  \right)  } +C\\ $$